# Is PCI Compliance is needed in Cordova Mobile App if I use Mobile Payment Gateway?

Tags: cordova, payment-gateway, pci-compliance, pci-dss

I want to implement the payment solution in my Cordova-Ionic Mobile App for iOS and Android. I am planning to use any third party Payment Gateways like Paypal SDK, Braintree etc or method that will redirect to the Gateway website. So do I want to implement the PCI DSS in my Application? I heard that the app should be follow the PCI Standards to handle any payment process. Also can anybody suggest any better payment solutions to use in Cordova-Ionic Mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

Even utilising something like PayPal requires that you are PCI Compliant.

So short answer is: Yes, you do want to implement the PCI DSS in your app.

Your provided payment gateways above are highly popular and would do the job for you, but of course it comes down to what you think is best, seamlessness / price / etc.